# How to set debug point in nopcommerce plugin into vs code application

Tags: visual-studio-code, nopcommerce

I am started to use vs code application to run nopCommerce project but I unable to set debug into plugin.

1. How to build nopCommerce plugin into vs code?
2. How to set debug point in nopcommerce plugin into vs code application

Answer (score 1):

Please refer this article https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/getting-started-with-nopcommerce-using-visual-studio-code/ and see how to configure and use launch.json for **.NET Core Launch(web)** configuration.